# Want to read variable value from remote file

Tags: bash

In one of my bash script I want to read and use the variable value from other script which is on remote machine.
How should I go ahead to resolve this. Any related info would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which kind of access do you have to the remote machine: ssh, ftp, http, smb, nfs, telnet, or even something else?

Comment: It has ssh access. And I just want to read the value of variable lets say 'uploadRate' from the script located at /root/

Comment: What do you mean by read a variable? Execute/read output from a script on another server, read a hard-coded variable from that script, etc...?

Comment: Just want to read hard-coded value from the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this (which is code I cannot currently test myself):

```
text=$(ssh yourname@yourmachine 'grep uploadRate= /root/yourscript')
```

It assumes that the value of the variable is contained in one line. The variable text now contains you variable assignment, presumably something like

```
uploadRate=1MB/s
```

There are several ways to convert the text/code into a real variable assignment in your current script, like evaluating the string or using grep. I would recommend

```
uploadRate=${text#*=}
```

to just remove the part up and including the `=`.

Edit: One more caveat to mention is that this only works if the original assignment does not contain variable references itself like in

```
uploadRate=1000*${kB}/s
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!!! This helped... I have one more follow up question: Can I read value of two variables with single ssh or do I need to have separate ssh for two variables.

Comment: Well, you could certainly grep for two variables in one go. It would then be slightly more difficult to extract them from `$text`.

Answer (score 0):

**I would tell two ways at least:**

1) You can simply redirect output to a file from remote server to your system with `scp` command...It would work for you.Then your script on your machine should read that file as an argument...

script on your machine:

```
read -t 50 -p "Waiting for argumet: " $1
```

It waits for output from remote machine,
Then you can

```
sshpass -p<password> scp user@host:/Path/to/file /path/to/script/
```

What you need to do:

You should tell the script from your machine, that the output from `scp` command is the argument(`$1`)

2)Run script from your machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

script='
#Your commands
'

sshpass -p<password> ssh user@host $script
```

And you have also another ways to run script to do sth with remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh user@machine 'command'
```

will print the standard output of the remote command.

Comment: `Reading a variable from a remote file` is a bit different than just `execute remote script`, though not completely clear what OP wants.

Comment: The question was not that clear. The title says remote file, while the question says remote script.